# Is there a way to use variable names for Smarty custom functions?

Tags: templates, smarty3

We are using custom functions for Smarty. Since we are building big templates using seperate sub-templates brought together, we face a problem: Sometimes a sub-template is used more than once in a page. So the user defined smarty function is declared twice.

We tried using a variable name for the functions like

```
{function name = menu_{$object_key}} 
... 
{/function}
```

but it didn't work. Did we do it wrong or is there no way to do this? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

PS. keeping track of "if a function is declared before" is impossible (or at least too hard) because of the complexity of our structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare your functions once, possible solution here is:

1. Make a separate template with custom functions you use inside:

**functions.tpl**

```
    {function name = menu} 
    ... 
    {/function} 

    {function name = another_func} 
    ... 
    {/function}
```

2. Then include it in your main template:

**main.tpl**

```
    {include file='functions.tpl'}
```

3. Call your functions in main template and any sub-templates

**main.tpl**

```
    {menu data=$menu}
    {include file='sub_template.tpl'}
```

**sub_template.tpl**

```
    {another_func}
```

Comment: Thank you but we have to include the **same** .tpl more than once (with different variables) in main.tpl so this won't work for us. 

These minor tpl's are building blocks like a banner, menu, content box etc. and they are dynamically brought together in different combinations to make web pages.